# How do I detect if the shift key was pressed when an onClick handler is invoked?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am writing an app for a Chromebook in Java.

In my `onClick()` event handler, how can I detect if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key was pressed when the click occurred?

Comment: But I don't have a Keyboard Event, only an onClick event

Comment: Sorry I made a mistaking thinking this was a javascript question. You can use 
isShiftDown() method if you can pass in a mouseEvent

Comment: Can you also give some code on how you are handling the onClick() event right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `boolean` that you put to `true` `onKeyDown()` and to `false` `onKeyUp()`.

Here is some Doc to help you: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to implement this:

```
int shiftHeld = 0;

@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT)
            shiftHeld = 0;
                return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT)
            shiftHeld = 1;
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```